# How to move Wishlist next to Add to Cart button?

Tags: magento2, layout

I tried,

```
 <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <move element="view.addto.wishlist" destination="product.info.media" />
 </page>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Changes:**

```xml
<move element="view.addto.wishlist" destination="product.info.media" />
```

to

```xml
<move element="product.info.addto" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" />
```

After that 
*delete all file from `var/cache` and `var/view_preprocessed`  and page_cache using `rm -rf  var/cache`and `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed` , `rm -rf  var/page_cache`*

Also flush the cache using `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: hi @Amit sir,is it possible to move add to cart button after short description using move element in product list page

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<move element="product.info.addto" destination="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" after="product.info.addtocart">
```